# What is the tag to make middle line

Tags: support, comments, markdown

I saw a comment formatted like this:

> @S.Mark: ̶T̶h̶a̶t̶s ̶g̶r̶e̶a̶t ;-)

What is the tag to make this middle line on a word?

Comment: you mean the strike ?

Comment: @Aristos Yes, .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When posting a question or answer there is `<strike>That's great</strike>`

Which will result in: <strike>That's great</strike>

But that will not work in a comment. So if this was actually stated within a comment, this is some Unicode trickery. A [combining long stroke overlay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough#Combining_characters) perhaps.

Edit: Hello world, my name is idiot. The answer is of course found within your question. Look at the source of it:

```
> @S.Mark: ̶T̶h̶a̶t̶s ̶g̶r̶e̶a̶t ;-)
```

So Unicode trickery indeed....sigh.

Comment: Or `<s>text</s>` for short.

Comment: Note that this won't work for comments, only answers.  It appears the person is using different characters that have the strikethrough in them rather than HTML markup.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, I was just finding that out as well. I think it's a combining long stroke overlay then, or some unicode trickery like that.

Comment: It looks kinda crappy as a comment; the strike lines don't quite line up, unlike when posted in a post.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, I noticed that. Not entirely sure what might be the cause there. :S Still can't get over the fact that the answer was within the question though.... :)

Comment: Yeah, my first instinct was to look in the source of the question, making it clear, but I didn't know how one might go about the unicode trickery to actually post it, so I didn't want to answer.

Comment: <del> is the more semantic tag (not that anyone cares)

Comment: @BenBrocka I'm starting to realize I have to stay out of anything related to HTML ;)